# How do i get the horizontal line behind buttons?

Tags: html, css

Hi there i was trying to create background line behind the buttons, before that i was using image but i want the line.

```
<div class="feedback-option">
  <div class="radios2">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="1">
      <span>1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="2" />
      <span>2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="3">
      <span>3</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="4">
      <span>4</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="5">
      <span>5</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/babuharry/azfmje8c/)

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "a line"?

Comment: Can you create an image illustrating how the result should look?!

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/azfmje8c/3/
If not, you need to provide more to go on by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no *line* in HTML. I have achieved the same by adding an empty `div` with required `background-color` and `height`. And with `position: absolute` to place it where required.

```
.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

P.S: I think you were trying to center the radios. For that I have changed `display: block;` for `.radios2`.

```css
.radios2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.radios2 label + label {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.radios2 input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    /* hidden but still tabable */
    position: absolute;
}

.radios2 input[type="radio"] + span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #eee;
    color: #555;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.radios2 input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in;
}

.radios2 input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    color: #D9E7FD;
    background-color: #4285F4;
}

.radios2 input[type="radio"]:focus + span {
    color: #fff;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-option">
<div class="line"></div>
  <div class="radios2">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="1">
      <span>1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="2" />
      <span>2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="3">
      <span>3</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="4">
      <span>4</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rating-1" value="5">
      <span>5</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea it looks exactly what i wanted, Thank You

Comment: Great. Please mark it as the right answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Almost what I'm looking for, does anyone know how to make the line only between the radio buttons, not full width ?